# Factor investing research

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I am studying the effects of market and funding liquidity on the returns of a portfolio formed on the Quality factor, QMJ (from: https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Datasets/Quality-Minus-Junk-Factors-Monthly).

I am using the Pastor and Stambaugh liquidity factor (https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/lubos-pastor/data) as proxy for market liquidity and the TED spread as a proxy for funding liquidity.

I have monthly returns of the QMJ portfolio in the sample period of July 1963 - December 2019 and I would like to know what the best way would be to run a time series regression of QMJ on these 2 liquidity factors.

I'm unsure of whether I should study the contemporaneous effect of market and funding liquidity on the QMJ portfolio returns or their lagged effect.
As such I would get 2 different regressions and I would like to know which one would result in better interpretations in my case.

1. QMJ(t) = PastorLiquidity(t) + TEDSpread(t) + (some other control variables, such as the Fama-French factors)

or

2. QMJ(t) = PastorLiquidity(t-1) + TEDSpread(t-1) + (some other control variables, such as the Fama-French factors)

What would be the difference in interpretation between these 2 regressions and which one would be better?
Thanks!

Btw, I'm using Stata